# Reset AFP permissions after uninstalling Mavericks Server?

Tags: macos, osx-server, permission, afp

I just uninstalled Mavericks Server by dragging it to the trash and I'm finding that my AFP server no longer has access to serve files from the root of each drive.  Can anyone help restore the default sharing permissions?

Comment: Are the permissions that are set on the drive that contains the share point set to allow "No Access" to "Others"? This might cause connection problems... Alternately - are those folders listed as shares in the File Sharing section of the Sharing System Preference? What do their permissions look like in that window?

Comment: I'm actually looking to share the entire drive from the root of several mounted volumes.  I did try adding the entire drives to the sharing pane, but that doesn't make the drives available with the normal, default permissions.

Here is a screenshot of the perms from the three drives.  The boot drive is on the left.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/9v3wzvf2dfrp0w7/Screenshot%202013-10-30%2018.21.48.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to configure the [AFP parameter `admin31GetsSp`](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH8440), to [allow administrators to mount entire volumes through AFP](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS2255) by performing this Terminal command:

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.AppleFileServer admin31GetsSp -bool false
```

It is most likely necessary to stop and start AFP services after making this change.

Comment: Hey Eddie,

That indeed fixed the problem.  I noticed that there are actually two values now:

 - admin31GetsSp
 - adminGetsSp

I set both to false and now I have access to the root volumes and Time Machine will now work again.  Thank you!